# A way to make a custom sorting logic in the Quote Line Editor of CPQ

Tags: javascript, salesforce

We are using Salesforce CPQ and our users wanted a way to force a particular product to always appear at the bottom of the Line Editor. We have this QCP plugin and I've tried to manipulate the array of the quoteLines in hopes that it displays the quoteLines based on the array index.

The array of quoteLines were being sorted but this sequence is not being followed when quote lines are displayed in the Quote Line Editor.

[Quote Line Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urT40.png)

I tried to manipulate the array by using splice and array.sort. I also tried to change the SBQQ_Number__c but didn't work.

What I was expecting was when FREIGHT is added, it will always appear as the last item.